# Google Maps API v3 returning a grey block

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm a newbie & this is my first post - pls forgive any protocol / formatting transgressions or the simplicity of my query - I could not find a conclusive solution elsewhere.

**Problem**
I'm trying to draw a map with little success - all I get is the grey box. Code is sourced from a combination of the Google API resource page and John Duckett's 'JavaScript & Jquery'.

**Suspected Cause**
My suspicion is its related to the API key, as I'm seeing no change in the API metrics on Google Developer - however, I'm not seeing any error in the Chrome console either.

Would appreciate any help - and how you identified the problem - thanks!

Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HR Sightings Page</title>
        <link href='css/styles.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google-map.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS - 'css/styles.css'

```
#map-canvas { 
    height: 500px; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

JavaScript - 'js/google-map.js'

```
{//Initialisation function to set up map
function init() {           
    var mapOptions = {                                                                  //Setup the map options
        centre: new google.maps.LatLng(-24.939602, 31.578375),                          //specify map centre
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,                                     //specify map type
        zoom: 8                                                                         //set default zoom
    };
    var venueMap;
    venueMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);   //draw the map
}

//Asyncronously load Google Maps api script once page is loaded
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');                                      //create <script> element
    script.type = 'text/JavaScript'
    script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?' + 
                    'key=AIzaSyBT5V-qRuEsNge9UDKsun74-Lf330Xlj7I&'+
                    'sensor=false&callback=init';                               
    document.body.appendChild(script);                                                  //add element to the page
}

//load the script
window.onload = loadScript;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo in your code (bracket in a wrong place), change:

```
venueMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas',mapOptions));
```

to:

```
venueMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

### EDIT

I forgot one more typo to mention (*centre* should be *center*):

```
centre: new google.maps.LatLng(-24.939602, 31.578375),
```

should be:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-24.939602, 31.578375),
```

Working example: http://js.do/nowa/62248

Comment: Thanks so much Ivan - careless mistakes on my part. Any quick way I could have picked these up? Using SublimeText 3, with minimal packages installed. Thanks again.